# How to disable universal volume controls in a page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app plays a track in the background with `AudioPlayerAgent` and the user can move between pages.

The problem is that I don't want the universal volume controls appear in one of those pages when the user presses the physical volume button. just like how we disable System Tray `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"`. Is it possible?

---

there is a way to set which controls appear when assigning the track, but this doesn't help in my case:

```
EnabledPlayerControls controls = EnabledPlayerControls.Pause |
    EnabledPlayerControls.Rewind |
    EnabledPlayerControls.FastForward;

AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(
    trackUri,
    trackTitle,
    trackBy,
    trackAlbum,
    trackAlbumArtUri,
    trackTag,
    controls);
```

Answer (score 0):

The experience is intentional that the volume control display is presented in a consistent cross-application experience when the volume buttons are pressed.

There currently is no API for overriding this behavior.

The same is true for example on Windows 8+ (the Volume indicator is now system defined and cannot be overridden/hidden).

Answer (score 0):

From what i found it's not so much appear but be enabled or disabled.

here is the sample code

```
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(
trackUri,
trackTitle,
trackBy,
trackAlbum,
trackAlbumArtUri,
trackTag,
EnabledPlayerControls.None);
```

Hope it helps